# How to attach a file while sending an email through shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I used the following code to send an email via shell script.

Code: `mail -s "subject" toaddress@gmail.com <<< "Body of the mail"`

It worked. But I want to attach a file while sending the mail. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of "mutt" if it's installed in your Linux machine.

```
$$ mutt -a "file_attachment"
```

Other options are the same as in the mail command.

Comment: What is ``$$``?

Comment: Just a prompt. In my machine prompt is set as $$. So did mention like that. It may differ for every machine and it can be anything based on the value set in PS1 variable. It doesn't mean anything in the command.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to attach file is to encode it. For example

```
uuencode file_to_attach file_to_attach|mail -s "subject" toaddress@gmail.com
```

will attach `file_to_attach` to the mail

Comment: @Velu, you mean command, right? So install it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mime-construct` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/mime-construct) or `makemime` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/makemime.1.html) if one of these tools is available.

Example from the `mime-contruct` man page:

> Send a plain text part and attach a file, setting the file's content type and --attachment name automatically.
>
> ```
> mime-construct --to "$recip" --subject "$file" \
> --string "Here's the file I told you about.$nl" \
> --file-attach "$file"
> ```

Of course it is also possible to create all MIME headers, boundaries and file encodings manually in your script. A (fairly complicated) example for this you can find in some scripts that are part of the (BSD licensed) HylaFAX software. Look for function `CreateMailMessage` in `notify.sh.in` and `common-functions.h.in` in the `util` directory of the source code. (see https://www.hylafax.org/, ftp://ftp.hylafax.org/source/)